# Access Log Sampler - Distributed testing

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am trying to test our site with JMeter's access log sampler, using distributed testing across several load generators.

On my local machine the test works fine. However, when I try to distribute it, then the test fails as the remote machines cannot seem to find the access log file that I want it to use.

I have copied the file to the remote machine and placed it in the jmeter/bin direcory, as I have it on the local/controller.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was starting the remote client in the home directory and not in the jmeter/bin directory.

I did have some issues configuring the log file name in the jmeter gui. It kept adding .\ to the start of the name or reverting to a different file that I had used earlier.

I got around that by editing the actual xml.